# Is it possible to pass views parameters without using URLs in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views

In `product_detail` in `views.py`, I use both `slug` and `pk` (which is passed through the urlpattern in `urls.py`) to look up for Product. I'd like to still use `pk` or `id` along with `slug` to look up for the `Product`. But, the case is, I don't want to pass `id` or `pk` parameter to urlpattern.

what I've:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/store/12/slug-of-product
                            ^^
```

what I want: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/store/slug-of-product`

`views.py`

```py
def product_detail(request, slug, pk):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug, pk=pk)
    return render(request, "store/product_detail.html", {"product": product})
```

`urls.py`

```py
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path("<int:pk>/<slug:slug>/", views.product_detail, name="product_detail"),
    #      ^^^^^
]
```

Expected:

`views.py`

```py
def product_detail(request, slug):
    pk = some_way_to_get_pk
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug, pk=pk)
    return render(request, "store/product_detail.html", {"product": product})
```

`urls.py`

```py
urlpatterns = [
    # ...
    path("<slug:slug>/", views.product_detail, name="product_detail"),
]
```

- Is it possible to do it with `HttpRequests` or some other way and how?
- Is it bad design?

I'd like to know for educational purpose.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An option is to pass it as a query parameter, like so `/slug-for-the-product/?pk=123`

Comment: Could you elaborate on your requirement?   Suppose you have a “view latest new product” url.  You could route to a view that looks up its id and then returns product_detail(id).  What are you looking to do from the user/client code’s perspective?  Is this a browser hyperlink?   Ajax in js?  Typed in address bar? Many exotic options, even if you ignore “good practice”, dont exist if coming from user entered urls.

Comment: [@JLPeyret](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1394353/jl-peyret) from a browser hyperlink sourced from `product.get_absolute_url`.